# Prove an arithmetic property of a partial recursive function

Tags: programming-languages, denotational-semantics

I have this program written in haskell :
[image]

I have to prove that:
    $(\forall a \in \mathbb{N})[!D_V [h](a) \Rightarrow log_2 (D_V[h](a) )\equiv 2  (mod$ $ 10) ]$.

The predicate $P_2$ for the $g$ function is obvious :
$P_2(f,g) \equiv (\forall x,y \in \mathbb{N})[!g(x,y) \Rightarrow g(x,y)\backsimeq xy]$.

But the predicate for the function $f$ which would give me authomaticaly the one for $h$ I have no idea what it should be.

Any ideas and help in solving this problem is welcomed :)

Notations:

- $D_V[h]$: denotational semantics with passing by value of the function $f$.
- $!F(x)$ means that $F$ is defined at point $x$.
- $F(x) \backsimeq V$ means has the value $V$ at the point $x$ or is undefined.

Comment: Please explain your notations. What is $D_V(a)$? What are $!$, $\equiv$ and $\backsimeq$? Also, please post the Haskell code as text.

Comment: From context, I gather that $\equiv$ is equality in the semantic domain (i.e. equality in $\mathbb{N}$)? And what's $P_2$? (You seem to use $P_2$ as a concept, rather than defining a particular notation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ computes the recurrence relation
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
4 & x \leq 1, \\
f(x-1)^2 f(x-2)^4 & x > 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Taking $\ell = \log_2 \circ f$, we get
$$
\ell(x) = \begin{cases}
2 & x \leq 1, \\
2\ell(x-1) + 4\ell(x-2) & x > 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Now, modulo 10 we have
$$
2 \cdot 2 + 4 \cdot 2 = 12 \equiv 2 \pmod{10}.
$$
An easy proof by induction then shows that $\ell(x) \equiv 2 \pmod{10}$ for all $x$.